# Wiremocks behaves differently in local machin and jenkins

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, wiremock

I have written some cucumber tests to test my service which calls multiple services one after another. So I have to put a delay in between to wait for all the calls to finish, while I run the tests locally. And it passes. But when the same tests went to Jenkins, it's failing.

I am using wiremocks to mock the services, and its mocking properly. But its not working properly in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

It is not cause of Jenkins itself but cause of environment and resources, obviously you have written tests shaped for your dev env and as you said you have delays, be aware that same code in different env will require different delays.